# How to inform the user if the user data would be erased after update the Android App?

Tags: android, user-data

I'm currently working on an Android update build, but each time when I overwrite the previous one with the new build, the prompt will say that "The application you are installing will replace another application. All previous user data will be saved."
But the problem is what I need is to erase the previous user data when updated to the new one. And is there a way to replace that warning text to some text that telling the user his user data will be erased? Or if there's an option in publish setting that could use the delete/install method instead of overwrite it?